# How to make a parent div that whenever I click anywhere inside it, a son div (jQuery UI draggable) will instantly go there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This is the list of things that I have no idea how to code better explained:

1. When you click anywhere in the bar, I want the button (black dot) to instantly go there, and automatically change the percentage displayed below it.
2. Also, when I drag the button to where I want and unclick/drop the button outside the bar div, the percentage below doesn't refresh. How can I correct that?

Here are the codes:

```js
<script src="jQueryUI/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery-ui.css"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
 $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  axis: 'x', containment: [-234,0,450,0]
 });
});
</script>

<script>
$( ".but1" ).click(function( event ) {
  var offset = $( ".but1" ).offset();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var conta = (offset.left - 752)/3.42;
  var posFinal = Math.round( conta );
  $( "#resp1" ).text( posFinal + "%" );
});
</script>
```

```css
.draggable {
 width: 700px;
 height: 0px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: relative;
}

#bar {
 width: 350px;
 height: 12px;
 background-color: #ff0a00;
 border-right: 350px solid #00b4ff;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#circle {
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

#discordo {
 position: relative;
 top: 65px;
 left: -386px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#concordo {
 position: relative;
 top: 31.8px;
 left: 390px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#organizado {
 position: relative;
 top: -70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="x.php" id="questions">
<h3>Pergunta 1</h3>
<p>Maconha deveria ser legalizada para uso recreacional</p>
<div id="organizado">
<p id="discordo">Discordo</p>
<p id="concordo">Concordo</p>
<div id="bar"> </div>
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
<div id="circle" class="but1"> </div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<p id="resp1"></p>
```

Here's the image so you can visualize it better.
[image: Print]

Comment: hmmm.... you mean like the jquery ui slider widget? look at it's source code.

Comment: Please provide some example code. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks like jQuery UI slider kind of creates the bar and handle for you. How do I just apply it to my handle and bar?

Comment: @MuriloGomes it looks like you are loading 2 jQuery libraries when only 1 is needed. It might be best to try making a jsfiddle example of your issue.

Comment: @Twisty what do you mean?

Comment: @Twisty https://stackoverflow.com/q/44782738/7627057

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use slider, here is a way you can do it.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/qpbzavwq/8/

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="x.php" id="questions">
  <h3>Pergunta 1</h3>
  <p>Maconha deveria ser legalizada para uso recreacional</p>
  <div id="organizado">
    <p id="discordo">Discordo</p>
    <p id="concordo">Concordo</p>
    <div id="bar-1" class="slider">
    </div>
    <p id="resp1"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#bar-1 {
  background-color: #00b4ff;
  margin: .4em .2em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#bar-1 .ui-slider-range {
  background-color: #ff0a00;
}

#bar-1 .ui-slider-handle {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0;
}

#discordo {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#concordo {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#bar-1").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    value: 65,
    create: function() {
      $("#discordo").position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top+2",
        of: "#bar-1 .ui-slider-handle"
      });
      $("#concordo").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left+25 top+2",
        of: "#bar-1 .ui-slider-handle"
      });
    },
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      $("#resp1").html(ui.value + "%");
      $("#discordo").position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top+2",
        of: "#bar-1 .ui-slider-handle"
      });
      $("#concordo").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left+25 top+2",
        of: "#bar-1 .ui-slider-handle"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In the future, just use the Demos: http://jqueryui.com/slider/ and review the API documentation.

Slider includes a lot of the features you were looking for. It's easily styled and themed using CSS.